# pass variable value to destructure object js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

from some input fields I get each id and value when they click, now I want to Destructur the id from the user and update the only field.

this my user

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({
        name: 'user name',
        email: 'user email',
        address: 'user address',
        phone: 'user phone',
    })
```

my html elements

```
<input className='w-100 mb-2' type="text"  name="phone"
                       onBlur={handleUserUpdate}
                       required id="phone"  placeholder='Phone'/>
                <input className='w-100 mb-2' type="text" name="address"
                       onBlur={handleUserUpdate}
                       placeholder="Address" required id="address"/>
```

my function

```
 const handleUserUpdate = event => {
        const {id, value} = event.target

        console.log(id, value)
        // here id should address or phone but error 
        const { id,...rest} = user
        const newUser = {value, ...rest}
        console.log(newUser)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

i assume the `variable id` value have same name as the key of object user

```
const handleUserUpdate = event => {
  const {id, value} = event.target
  setUser(prev => {...prev, [id] : value })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Destructure the value from the event
const { name, value } = event.target

// Set the new state
setUser({
   ...user
   [name]: value
})
```

Comment: this process create a new new property but I need update the user address or phone number by using their id name but I don't know to how to Destructure a variable's value from a object